# Why my contribution in Git shows less than other co-workers?

Tags: git, github

I have forked the master branch to mine, and all branches I create I make a PR on the master branch.
I make commits and PR everyday and are being merged to master everyday.
I am contributing more than my co-workers. 
But, my contributions show less and also when I click on the commits, the last commit was from a month ago. I am not sure why recent commits are not being counted? 
The problem is that the manager sees this and sees that I am contributing less, which is not true.

What can I do?

Comment: If "PR" refers to "Pull Requests", this is exactly what they are: **requests**. Just because you've made commits to a particular branch doesn't mean they've been approved and will show up as commits pulled into a (ostensibly) `master` branch. Make sure you're looking at the right branch, and maybe talk to your peers/manager(s) about it. In any case, this is a highly-localized issue that can't be diagnosed without a mountain of other contextual information regarding your organization's back-end processing of commits within Git.

Comment: No all Pull Requests were approved and merged with master.

Comment: Also a possibility, wherever is backing the gui in which you "click on the commits" is not getting updated from the source of truth.

Comment: If your manager's metrics are that bad, there's not much you can do... productivity measured by the number of PRs? or number of commits? Both are absurd.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Github Logic:

> Committing anything to any repository’s default branch
>
> Committing anything to any repository’s gh-pages branch
>
> Opening any issue
>
> Proposing any pull request

**Due to all of this, the GitHub Contribution can’t really be relied on as a definitive source of actual contributions to your project, nor can it be relied on as a definitive source of your dedication to your craft as a developer.**